# How to validate Web Part property value?

Tags: web-part, validation, web-part-property

A custom web part has custom web part properties. I would like to validate with custom server side code when user changes property value (or when properties are bing saved). Is that possible? Can I show an error message in the tool pane describing the problem that occurred?

Example: I have a web part where user needs to enter a list name (in a property). I would like to check if list with such a name exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could create a custom EditorPart which creates a custom interface in which you verify the input. Check this out: [Web Part Properties - part 2 - Editor Parts](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Web-Part-Properties-part-2-Editor-Parts.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

I hope this can help you, althought I have not tested it. You can find an example here: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2010/06/validating-web-part-properties.html

```
private string _webPartContentLink = null;
 [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("Services")]
        [WebDisplayName("Enter WebPart Content Link")]
        [WebDescription("Enter WebPart Content Link")]
        public string WebPartContentLink 
        {
            get
            {
                if (_webPartContentLink == null)
                {
                    _webPartContentLink = string.Empty;
                }
                return _webPartContentLink;
            }
            set 
            {
                if (!value.StartsWith("http://"))
                      throw new WebPartPageUserException("The WebPart Content Link is not valid");
                }

                _webPartContentLink = value;
             }
          }
```

Comment: Should change Exception to WebPartPageUserException. If I remember correctly Exception will generate a default value for the user.

Comment: Sure, I caught the first example in the page. I'll edit it now. Please vote if you like my answer, I need some reputation :)

Comment: Thanks @Abu Hamzah. I figured it would be nicer to have all this information in one place. :)

Comment: +1 really nice answer! Maybe you can include an example of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages` property in addition to the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` you have above.

Comment: I will try to find a moment to include the example of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages property` property. But for the moment, here there is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Wictor said, remember to define your own ValidationGroup when you are using custom or out of the box ASP.NET validators, that way you dont get interference from other validation controls that might be on the same page when you do a post back (maybe a subject for your book Wictor?:-)

Comment: Already in there mate! And some other neat tips and tricks!

Comment: And what if this web part is part of sandboxed solution? I presume this will not work without a custom proxy?

Comment: No probs Toni, EditorParts work fine within the SB!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following article: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/SharePoint-Web-Parts-with-jQuery-and-the-Web-ToolPart.aspx

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for reference. See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a custom editor part with a textbox and ASP.NET validation control, e.g a RegularExpressionValidator. This gives you client-side validation on the property. The only disadvantage I can see with that solution is that the custom editor parts are always displayed in the top (which quite anoying...).

See this MSDN article for a walk-through: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx#Y4419

Comment: FYI.. I've moved your answer from the [duplicate question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/18886/2070).