# how to validate custom web part property?

Tags: web-part, validation, custom-web-part-property

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate Web Part property value?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/how-to-validate-web-part-property-value)

below is a custom prop and a code that i am using for my custom web part, my question is, how to validate a custom web part and my requirement is that, when the user enter `WebPartContentLink` link i want to make sure that it starts with `http://` any idea how to implement ?

```
private string _webPartContentLink = null;
 [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        [WebBrowsable(true)]
        [System.ComponentModel.Category("Services")]
        [WebDisplayName("Enter WebPart Content Link")]
        [WebDescription("Enter WebPart Content Link")]
        public string WebPartContentLink 
        {
            get
            {
                if (_webPartContentLink == null)
                {
                    _webPartContentLink = string.Empty;
                }
                return _webPartContentLink;
            }
            set 
                {

                    _webPartContentLink = value;
                }
          }



PageViewerWebPart oWebPart = new PageViewerWebPart();
oWebPart.ContentLink = WebPart.WebPartContentLink.ToString();
Controls.Add(oWebPart);
```