# Custom Tool Part Validation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, toolpart

I have created custom tool part. I want to validate tool part control.

I need functionality that validate control and if i click on "**OK**" Button then if validation fire then tool part must be open with validation message.

Answer (score 0):

There is already answer for this question in StackExchange see the [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/1980/20912)
You could create a custom EditorPart which creates a custom interface in which you verify the input.